# Pushed to Git, everything disappeared?

Tags: git, github

So I'm new to working in Ruby on Rails. I committed everything and pushed it up to git, then my project reverted back to an old version. My most recent version is safely stored on git, but now all the original files on my computer are gone and replaced by older versions of them. What's going on?

EDIT: more details:

```
git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .DS_Store
#   modified:   app/.DS_Store
#   modified:   app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss
#   modified:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   app/assets/.DS_Store
#   app/assets/images/.DS_Store
#   public/chat.png
#   public/groups.png
#   public/join-free.png
#   public/login-button.png
#   public/meetups.png
#   public/people.png
#   public/posts.png
#   public/profile.png
#   public/stream.png
#   public/streambaby.png
#   public/streamblue.png
#   public/streamlime.png
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git add .
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git commit -m "home page basic"
[master 49921d4] home page basic
 Committer: Laser Nite <lasernite@Lasers-MacBook-Pro.local>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 18 files changed, 144 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 app/assets/.DS_Store
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/.DS_Store
 rewrite app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss (100%)
 rewrite app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb (100%)
 create mode 100644 public/chat.png
 create mode 100644 public/groups.png
 create mode 100644 public/join-free.png
 create mode 100644 public/login-button.png
 create mode 100644 public/meetups.png
 create mode 100644 public/people.png
 create mode 100644 public/posts.png
 create mode 100644 public/profile.png
 create mode 100644 public/stream.png
 create mode 100644 public/streambaby.png
 create mode 100644 public/streamblue.png
 create mode 100644 public/streamlime.png
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git branch
* master
  work
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git push
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 60.94 KiB, done.
Total 27 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:lasernite/meetumea.git
   a78c8f0..49921d4  master -> master
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git co work
Switched to branch 'work'
Lasers-MacBook-Pro:meetumea lasernite$ git status
# On branch work
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I then noticed that all my files were old versions and all my new images were gone from the public folder. I just ran rm -rf meetumea and then cloned my project from github, so the problem is solved. I'd still like to know what happened, though.

Comment: Not sure what happened, need more details.  I would try pulling from Github, if that doesn't work you may have to revert to a past state of your local repo.

Comment: What are the exact commands that you ran?

Comment: edited- added everything that went through terminal.

Comment: Huh, I don't see any evidence of the problem in that terminal transcript.

Comment: I almost fell off my chair I was so confused. The code before that is just a bunch of responses from the rails server, because I had it running as I was developing. The only code after what I posted is me restarting the rails server. It came up with the rails default page which freaked me out and then I immediately came here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you created a branch called "work" previous to what you pasted in your question. You then committed some changes to the master branch ('newcommit' below) and pushed that. You then checked out the "work" branch which branches from before the new commits. That means it won't contain the new commits. If you were to checkout master again you'd see your changes again.

```
newcommit (master)
  |
  |
  |                  othercommit (work)
  |                    /
basecommit------------'
```

So if you checkout 'work' then newcommit is not going to be on that branch. Or possibly there were never any new commits on the 'work' branch, in which case 'work' still points to basecommit:

```
newcommit (master)
  |
  |
  |
  |
basecommit (work)
```

So if you checkout 'work' you're back to before newcommit existed. Remember that branches in git are simply pointers to commits that move automatically as you add commits (and tags are pointers that don't move automatically).